# Which dependency is missing in my angular Module?

Tags: angularjs

I defined an angular module and angular keeps complaining about a missing "$routeProvider". I don't understand as i defined the 'ngRoute' as dependency of my module.

My Code:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var FlightlistController = function () {
      //code comes inside here
    };

    angular.module('flights', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/flightslist', {
                controller: 'FlightsController',
                controllerAs: 'flights',
                templateUrl: 'modules/flight/list.view.html'
            })
        }])

    .controller('FlightsController', ['$routeProvider', FlightlistController])

})();
```

[The error i get](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$routeProviderProvider%20%3C-%20$routeProvider%20%3C-%20FlightsController)

Comment: have you included angular-route after angular ?

Comment: please update the question with the code where you have included js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `$routeProvider` from controller definition.

```
.controller('FlightsController', ['$routeProvider', FlightlistController])
```

just use

```
.controller('FlightsController', FlightlistController);
```

Hope this helps now.

Comment: I've double checked that. My index.html file includes the flights.js where i have the code as posted above.

    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/flights/flights.js"></script>

Comment: That's nice. Proposed solution let's the error go away :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject it in your controller function as a param

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var FlightlistController = function ($routeProvider) {
      //code comes inside here
    };

    angular.module('flights', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/flightslist', {
                controller: 'FlightsController',
                controllerAs: 'flights',
                templateUrl: 'modules/flight/list.view.html'
            })
        }])

    .controller('FlightsController', ['$routeProvider', FlightlistController])

})();
```

Comment: I think, as long as i don't have any Code inside my var FlightslistController = function();

Anyway, I tried your suggestion but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the input parameter of the controller (function FlightlistController).

var FlightlistController = function () need to be changed to var FlightlistController = function ($routeProvider)

And as per your error message check have you specify the script reference for ngRoute. if not place it after you add the script reference of angular.